# Paypal: How to associate checkout id in the responde with the transaction id in the dashboard?

Tags: paypal

I am doing the simple integration of paypal buttons on my website, using javascript.

I got a reply, using sandbox, like this

```
create_time: "2020-04-22T09:23:59Z"
id: "3Y914122MY820580S"
intent: "CAPTURE"
links: [{…}]
payer:
address: {country_code: "IT"}
email_address: "sb-yuz43i687312@personal.example.com"
name: {given_name: "John", surname: "Doe"}
payer_id: "PAV4AZG5BTYE2"
purchase_units: [{…}]
status: "COMPLETED"
update_time: "2020-04-22T09:24:23Z"
```

Also, opening the `links` array, I have only the following, with same id

```
"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/3Y914122MY820580S"
```

But, opening the sandbox dashboard of receiving paypal acocunt i see this

[image]

How can I associate the checkout id `3Y914122MY820580S` with the transaction id `289895873G149713E` ?

I have the need to save into db something to be able to verify the paypal transaction in a future moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the code I need more deeply nested.

Having `json_result` the json data returned from Paypal, in cas of success, of course, the Id of payment can be found at

```
json_result->purchase_units[0]->payments->captures[0]->id
```

It can be succesfully used in a link of type

```
https://www[.sandbox].paypal.com/activity/payment/<id>
```

So merchant can easily see transaction details